# Inherit javadoc, without generating docs for inherited source

Tags: java, ant, documentation, javadoc

I would like `class B` to inherit the Javadoc from an interface that it implements, `interface A`. I have included the source for `interface A` in my Javadoc command, and `class B` correctly inherits the documentation.

Now I'm wondering if I can make the links it generates point to `interface A`'s documentation on the web, rather than duplicating it on my site, i.e. the "Specified by:" links will link to an external page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, yes.
For being able to include inherited documentation, the source of interface A has to be findable in the sourcepath of javadoc, but should not be in the list of packages passed to `javadoc` for documentation creation.
For linking, use the `-link` parameter. I just tried this (with the ant javadoc task):

```
<javadoc destdir="docs">
  <sourcepath>
    <!-- source of your class B -->
    <pathelement location="src" /> 
    <!-- source of external interface A -->
    <pathelement location="../example-src/src" />
  </sourcepath>

  <!-- your packages, to generate the docs for -->
  <package name="com.personal.myproject.*" />

  <!-- the location of the online documentation -->
  <link href="http://example.com/javadoc/"/>
</javadoc>
```

To command line javadoc, I think this translates like this (unix syntax, one line):

```
 javadoc -sourcepath ../example-src/src:src
         -d docs
         -link http://example.com/javadoc/
         -subpackages com.personal.myproject
         (other options...)
```

where

- `class B` is in package `com.personal.myproject`,
- `interface A` is in package `com.example`,
- my own sources are in `src`,
- the sources for interface A are in `../example-src/src`.

In a example class created for this, javadoc would copy the documentation from `A.methodName()` to `B.methodName()`, but link to the online documentation at `http://example.com/javadoc/com/example/A.html#methodName()`.

Thanks for asking this question, I always wanted to do this :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped. Turns out I was including a jar of the same classes ("interface A") on my classpath, which was preventing the inherited documentation appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Huge credit to [Paŭlo Ebermann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923682/1512961) for pointing me in the right direction for my set up. Please read that answer first as it makes sense of this while I am just providing an additional way to configure the solution.

---

So thought I'd share what I went with for anyone managing their project with maven and using [maven-javadoc-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html) as part of their build process to generate their docs.

As part of the plugin's configuration you can specify a group of links to include. [Here is the bit](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/links-configuration.html) that specifically covers configuring links.

And here is a sample linking external documentation for selenium and java se for packaging in a jar to deploy with my project. The beauty is that these javadocs in my project just link out to the external ones seemlessly.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <links>
            <link>http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/</link>
            <link>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/${project.java.version}/docs/api/</link>
        </links>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

Btw, if you found anything on this page useful, please link to it somewhere. Finding this page on google was too difficult and this is a really nice thing to have.