# Comments on @Override methods

Tags: android, comments, overriding, javadoc

My question is not really a programming problem..

I must comment my code for the JavaDoc, but I think it's a bit strange to re-comment existing methods (I think about `@Override` methods).

For example, I override the method `onListItemClick`, is there a solution to "redirect" the user to the comment of the overridden method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use: `/** {@inheritDoc} */` or `{@link  package.class#member  label}`

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#{@inheritDoc}](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@inheritDoc%7D)

Comment: Just a note: [For `{@inheritDoc}` to work, the sources of the inherited class or interface must be included in sourcepath of the javadoc run.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4922124/600500)

Answer (score 8):

Try `{@inheritDoc}` attribute. This should do what you need.

You also can add some additional help comments after or before this tag. Here is an example from android source code:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 *
 * Note that if you're calling on a local binder, this always returns true
 * because your process is alive if you're calling it.
 */
public boolean isBinderAlive() {
    return true;
}
```