# Inheriting javadoc from libraries in archive files

Tags: java, ant, documentation, javadoc

It's possible to inherit JDK documentation into methods you've overridden/implemented when generating Javadoc. (for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922124/inherit-javadoc-without-generating-docs-for-inherited-source).)

This works by adding a directory containing the JDK source to the Javadoc -sourcepath. I assume that the same thing will happen if I unzip the source for any of my library dependencies.

Is it possible to inherit documentation without unzipping all of the source? This would allow full documentation using a path that I can create from Ivy/Maven or whatever.

Perhaps it's possible to fool Javadoc into using some sort of zip path?

I realise I can link to documentation elsewhere on the web – also useful, but different.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html):

> Explicitly inherit comment with [`{@inheritDoc}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@inheritDoc%7D) tag - Insert the inline tag `{@inheritDoc}` in a method main description or `@return`, `@param` or `@throws` tag comment -- the corresponding inherited main description or tag comment is copied into that spot.
>
> The source file for the inherited method need only be on the path specified by [-sourcepath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#sourcepath) for the doc comment to actually be available to copy. Neither the class nor its package needs to be passed in on the command line.

Comment: Java 6 (not that it makes a difference in this case): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#@inheritDoc

Comment: @assylias - Thanks. I guess I need to update my bookmarks. :)

Comment: The second paragraph suggests that the source file (presumably unzipped) needs to be on the `-sourcepath`. My question is whether this can be done just giving it a jar/zip file with the source file.

Comment: @Joe - Did you try putting a jar/zip file on the source path? I think that it will look inside.

Comment: @TedHopp you're right, it looks inside the jars. Unfortunately it also tries to generate Javadocs for everything it finds. Even when you specify the packages you want, it still processes everything in the source path. It tries to find all dependencies of the classes it finds, so you also need all of the optional dependencies. It fails the build when it can't find everything it wants. This feels like a goose chase.

Answer (score 1):

I'm accomplishing this with my maven project configuration like this so that the core java documentation that gets linked always matches my compilation version. And I want to link all of the documentation for selenium as this is part of a page object framework that relies heavily on it. I'm sure we could adapt this approach to the set up that you have.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <links>
            <link>http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/</link>
            <link>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/${project.java.version}/docs/api/</link>
        </links>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

At it's core this is the same as using the command line options for javadoc to link to things on the web, like in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923682/1512961) that you linked. Just need to parameterize the url it links to.

> To command line javadoc, I think this translates like this (unix
>   syntax, one line):
>
> ```
> javadoc -sourcepath ../example-src/src:src
>         -d docs
>         -link http://example.com/javadoc/
>         -subpackages com.personal.myproject
>         (other options...)
> ```

---

Doh! Just realized this all assumes your external libraries are hosting their documentation somewhere. I guess if that is not the case, maybe you can explore generating a javadoc jar for the external library and linking with a jar style uri. At least then you only introduce a single new artifact to the project.

Answer (score 1):

In JDK 1.8.0u121, `-sourcepath` does accept ZIP files, such as the `src.zip` which comes with the JDK itself.